# What's the difference between INPUT and INPUT_PULLUP?

Tags: arduino, hardware, software, pins

On newer Arduinos, one can set pinMode to one of three states: `OUTPUT`,`INPUT`, and `INPUT_PULLUP`.

[This page](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Constants) says:

> The Atmega chip on the Arduino has internal pull-up resistors (resistors that connect to power internally) that you can access. If you prefer to use these instead of external pull-down resistors, you can use the INPUT_PULLUP argument in pinMode(). This effectively inverts the behavior, where HIGH means the sensor is off, and LOW means the sensor is on.

I'm  rather sure that inverting the behavior isn't the only thing that it does, though.

What does `INPUT_PULLUP` do? What makes it different from `INPUT`, and  how does one decide which one to use?

Comment: INPUT_PULLUP was added with IDE 1.0.1.  It is irrelevant which Arduino board you use, they all support PULLUPs.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The default is `INPUT` which sets up the pin as an `INPUT`.  If the pin is totally disconnected, it will randomly read `HIGH` and `LOW`.   If you tie it to +5V or 0V, it will obviously read `HIGH` or `LOW`.

Internal to the Arduino, the Atmega chip has internal pullup resistors with a value around 20k ohm. (See the [DigitalPins](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins) documentation for more details)  These resistors can be optionally connected internally using `INPUT_PULLUP`.   This is functionally (and electrically) equivalent to connecting a ~20k ohm resistor between the pin and +5V, the only difference is that it requires no external components and you can turn it on and off in software during the execution of your program.

So why pull-ups and not pull-downs?  There are likely several reasons for it, but when wiring buttons or switches or anything "normally open", you only have to tie them to ground, you don't need to run +5V out to them.   Since most boards are going to be designed with large ground pours for shielding reasons anyway, tying to ground is practically reasons.

Some more featured ICs like ARM chips have both pull ups and pull downs, but the 8-bit AVR line only comes with pull-ups.  You just have to remember that `HIGH` is "open" and `LOW` is "closed".

Comment: Upvote.  FYI, according to the documentation the internal pull-ups are 20K, not that it makes much difference from 50K.  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins

Answer (score 14):

Note that previous to 1.0.1, you could turn on pullups by using `digitalWrite()`.  And you still can.

The code:

```
pinMode(13, INPUT);
digitalWrite(13, HIGH); // Turns internal pull-up on
digitalWrite(13, LOW);  // Turns internal pull-up off
```

This is an important distinction because `INPUT_PULLUP` obviously turns on the pull-up resistor.  However, less obvious, is that starting with 1.0.1, simply calling `INPUT` forces the pull-up to be turned off.  (Previously, the state of the pull-up stayed the same).

To see how a pin operates with and without pull-ups, watch the following videos.

Floating pin on an oscilloscope: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBIBFLYCjMM

With Pull-Up enabled: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAIw7LLVl-U

Full tutorial video on Pull-Ups (note that I made this before INPUT_PULLUP was added to the Arduino library): http://www.youtube.com/watch?&v=jJnD6LdGmUo

Comment: Very clever.  Thank you for writing this.  Upvote.

Comment: Two first videos are gone, but the third one is still there and does the job :-)

Comment: I've re-enabled the first two, although the others cover it. Also search "AddOhms Pull Up" on youtube for a couple I did later.